# SQLite locking for xFileSize and xTruncate

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sqlite, locking

I'm writing a [VFS](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/io_methods.html) for SQLite using [APSW's VFS layer](https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/vfs.html): https://github.com/michalc/sqlite-memory-vfs, and trying to make sure it allows concurrent access safely

I *think* that xRead and xWrite are protected by the SQLite+VFS locking mechanism - xRead is protected the SHARED lock, and xWrite by EXCLUSIVE.

But: what about xFileSize and xTruncate? Are these protected by SHARED and EXCLUSIVE locks as well? Asking because the underlying data structures used in the VFS to store the files are are *not* thread safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, I have only ever seen xFileSize not wrapped by a SHARED lock and xTruncate not wrapped by an EXCLUSIVE on the "-journal" files for a database.

And I *think* that SQLite's locking mechanism on the primary file would protect these.

It's not exactly ironclad proof admittedly - just evidence.